# EventHandler Method Looping Forever

Tags: c#, events, event-handling

### Issue

---

I am using Streamcoders when creating an application to live stream. I am trying to work a method to handle when the clients internet disconnects when he is streaming. I want it to hit a method and display a message box and for the user to restart the stream.

Instead the method keeps getting hit therefore i get a spam a message boxes on my screen.

### Code

---

So Streamcoders have an EventHandler for an Error and this is what i am subscribing to:

```
public RtspManager manager = new RtspManager();

public LiveMainViewModel()
{
    manager.OnError += new StreamCoders.Network.OnError(OnErrorStream);
}
```

Then this is the method that keeps getting looped when the internet disconnects:

```
private void OnErrorStream(object sender, SocketError error)
{
    if (MessageBox.Show("An error has occured during your live stream. Please check your Internet and click 'OK' to restart.","Error",MessageBoxButton.OKCancel,MessageBoxImage.Error) == MessageBoxResult.OK)
    {
        StopStreamSettings();
        videoStreamTimer.Stop();

        manager = new RtspManager();

        StreamSettings();

        ExpectedBitrate = BitrateConversion(config.Bitrate);
        videoStreamTimer.Start();
    }
}
```

I want the method to get hit and the message box to display, wait for the user to fix the error (*Reconnect the internet*) and then click 'OK' and the code runs.

Comment: You must call the Stop methods **before** you display the dialog.  If you don't then it isn't stopped while the dialog is displayed and the event keeps firing, adding ever more dialog boxes.

Comment: @HansPassant When you say the 'Stop' methods where would i find this? Do i also call the stop at the start of the method or at the end?